# Securing our webpage C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, http-status-code-403

I'm Developing one webpage where users can updates their post as images, videos and text . Here What i wants to do is, using one url i'll post their details when they submit and update it in similar page . so that url must be hidden and anyone tried to access that url it must reply 403 error . Is that possible ? Any suggestions ?

Edit : Url Hidden means when users submitting their post , our posting url should not be displayed in url tab of browser ..

thanks

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: What do you mean "url must be hidden"? If you perform any operation (post/get/head....) it will be known to a user...

Comment: I've edited @AlexeiLevenkov

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to not show the url in the browser, then simply post the form using ajax/jquery. This way the url will not be visible.